# Build project from MSBuild to different out directory

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm spent a lot of time on problem with MSBuild task and out directory.
This is my target task from msbuild file:

```
<Target Name="CompileService">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(ServiceProj)"
            Targets="Clean;Rebuild"
            Properties="Configuration=%(BuildConfig.Identity);
            OutputPath=..\..\..\..\..\$(OutServiceDirectory)\%(BuildConfig.AppServer)"/>
    </Target>
```

Files goes to two folders some dll's and exe files goes to one directory, different dll's goes to different directory abowe first one.

When the ouput path looks like:

OutputPath=D:\SomeLocation\$(PackageTempBackServiceProj)\%(BuildConfig.AppServer)"/>

Works fine. All files goes to that folder.

Problem: I don't want to hardcode path. How to write correct output directory.

Comment: Have you tried running msbuild from the command line instead of writing it into your XML? Then you can specify the properties using the `/P` parameter. That would also allow you to expand the path you are trying to output to before running the msbuild command.

Comment: No, because it's a part of larges solution. Rest works fine. I need build windows service for dev\test enviroments which are stored in parameter file. I build because a need application.cofig transform for each enviroment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the Microsoft.Common.targets you will see that the default definition of the Build target is defined as follows:

```
<Target
    Name="Build"
    Condition=" '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true' "
    DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"
    Outputs="$(TargetPath)"/>
</Target>
```

The purpose of this target is to define what targets it depends on and to create the outputs. So if you want to all files go to one directory, you have to specify an absolute path for /p:OutputPath=””, because a relative path will go relative to each project file.

As an alternative solutions for you don`t want use the absolute path and could not specify the properties using the /P parameter, you can try to use **below workarounds**:

(1) Use the **Move task** from [Move Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595163.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to combine MSBuild output files to one folder:

```
    <ItemGroup>
     <FilesToMove Include="..\..\..\..\..\ $(OutServiceDirectory)\%(BuildConfig.AppServer)\*.dll"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CombineOutputFile" AfterTargets="Build">
     <Move SourceFiles="@(FilesToMove)" DestinationFolder="${DestinationFolder}" />
    </Target>
```

(2) Extends the behavior of the normal build to create the proper outputs, refer [How to get all generated outputs](http://sedodream.com/2007/11/21/MSBuildHowToGetAllGeneratedOutputs.aspx) for more detail:

```
<Target Name="Build"
    DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"
    Outputs="@(AllOutputs->'%(FullPath)')">

<CreateItem Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*">
  <Output ItemName="AllOutputs" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Hope those could help you.

Comment: Can I read Working directory from Jenkins and insert into Outputs ?

Comment: @Bartolini, as far as I know, the answer is yes, but I`m not Jenkins experts. For this question, I suggest you can submit a new post, you will get a more professional answer. If above answer resolve your question? If yes, you can mark it answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? Thanks.